# Email not getting sent for multiple recipients in case of duplicate emails

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to send email to multiple recipients using

```
is_multiple=True,
```

which is working fine.

But only one mail is getting sent out of two when I try to include same mail with `+` symbol again

```
e.g abc@gmail.com, abc+test@gmail.com
```

when I send mail to the above two mail recipients from gmail directly, even if I add `+`
to the mail, it will still be delivered as two mails for the same email.

But this is not the behaviour in sendgrid, only one of the recipient is receiving the mail

```
message = Mail(
    from_email=From(self.sender, "Test"),
    to_emails=all_recipients,
    is_multiple=True,
)
```

```
all_recipients = [
            To(
                email=recipient["email"],
                dynamic_template_data=recipient["template_data"],
            )
            for recipient in recipients_and_template_data
        ]
```

Comment: Is `all_recipients` a list of email addresses?

Comment: It contains `To` object. which has the list of emails and templates. updated in the question now

Comment: When it was sent to one recipient, did the template load correctly? I personally haven't seen a To constructor used like this (passing in email and template), so I'm not sure it works. Usually, I see it like `To("email@gmail.com")`. So what would happen if you removed `dynamic_template_data` then pass the template in Mail as an argument? What happens when you print out all_recipients? Does it look like `["email@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"]`?

Comment: @AnthonyDellavecchia, With the above code we can able to send email to multiple recipients at the same time. Once for the mentioned scenario it's not working as expected